# OData Query parameters are not working in 8.2.3

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, odata, url-routing, odata-v4

We have migrated our API from 2.2 to 6.0 and we are upgraded OData also to 8.2.3.
Before update custom methods with query parameters are working well but after update no luck.
Basic OData methods and functionalities are working well and good after update too.

Below is my controller code.

```
public partial class DepartmentController : ODataController
 {
    [HttpGet, Route("api/v1/department/getDepartmentsByCompany")]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQuery]
    public Task<BaseResponse<IEnumerable<Department>>> GetDepartmentByCompany([FromQuery] int id, [FromQuery] FunctionalType? functionalType)
    {
        try
        {
            return "success data";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.LogException(ex, _hostingEnvironment);
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
    
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet] 
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQuery]
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Department>> Get()
    {
        return _implementation.GetAllAsync();
    }
    
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQuery] 
    public Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results.SingleResult<Department> Get(int key)
    {
        return _implementation.GetAsync(key);
    }
 }
```

And Program.cs looks like

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(g =>
{
    g.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
}).AddOData(opt =>
    {
        var batchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler();
        opt.AddRouteComponents("api/v1", DIRegister.GetEdmModels(), batchHandler);
        opt.Count().Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().SetMaxTop(int.MaxValue);
        opt.EnableQueryFeatures(int.MaxValue);
        opt.EnableAttributeRouting = false;
    }).AddJsonOptions(g =>
    {
        g.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = true;
    });
```

I am getting below exception

```
The key value (getComapnyByDepartment) from request is not valid. The key value should be format of type 'Edm.Int32'
```

and inner exception as
`Expected literal type token but found token getComapnyByDepartment`

Am i missing anything here or configuration issues.
I have gone through the MS [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/) no luck here too

Sample code is [uploaded here](https://github.com/itsmegopi/OdataTrial)

We have raised bug in OData you can see [here](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/1152)

Comment: make sure that your attribute routing is aligned with the new version's requirements. You're using `[Route("api/v1/department/getDepartmentsByCompany")]` which might not be correctly interpreted in the new version. In your `Program.cs`, Try enabling attribute routing by setting `opt.EnableAttributeRouting = true;`.

Comment: The error message indicates an issue with the key value: it's expecting an `Edm.Int32`, but is getting `getComapnyByDepartment`. This suggests a mismatch between the expected key type and the provided value. Make sure your routing template in the controller matches the expected key type. If `getComapnyByDepartment` is meant to be a method call, ensure it's correctly configured as a function or action in OData.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I tried EnableAttributeRouting,EnableEndpointRouting  switching different values and instead of route used HttpGet attribute also but no luck.